# Unwanted output in simple python script

Tags: python, loops, character, led

Hello i'm starting with python on a RPI B+, i made a simple while loop but i'm getting weird output.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
while 1:
    print "LED OFF"
    GPIO.output(3,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
    print "LED ON"
    GPIO.output(3,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When GPIO3 is LOW it repeatedly outputs **^[[B** until it's HIGH again.
The letter B changes depending on the pin i'm using.

Why is this happening? It looks like it is registering a button press, but i'm certainly not pressing any buttons nor do i have any input on the GPIO.

I tried another keyboard but it didn't make a difference.

This is the output i'm getting from this :

```
LED OFF
^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[BLED ON
^[[BLED OFF
^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[BLED ON
^[[BLED OFF
^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[BLED ON
^[[BLED OFF
```

I should note that the LED's do blink correctly.

EDIT :

When i switch focus to the text editor while the program runs, the output is normal but the down button gets pressed which causes the cursor inside the text editor to go down.
I'm starting to think this is a OS problem, i'm using the Porta Pi image, i use that img for my arcade cabinet so i thought i might aswell use it for this.

Comment: Seems very strange. This probably changes nothing, but I've always used "True/False" or "1/0" instead of "High/Low".    Also, what happens if you comment out ALL of the gpio code. Just to make sure it's not some weird OS thing and narrow down the problem.

Comment: When i comment out GPIO.output(3,GPIO.LOW) and GPIO.output(3,GPIO.HIGH) the strange output goes away. I also figured out that ^[[D is the down arrow key.

I tried the true/flase 0/1 thing but it doesn't work, it probably requires different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting with Python on a RPI B++ too. Lots of fun!! But anyway: this won't solve your problem I guess, but I was asking myself while looking at your script: shouldn't you put tabs before all lines after the while?

Comment: Yes, i do have that in my original script, forgot to add them here.

Answer (score 0):

Me again, looking over a few of my scripts for RPi, I think your output syntax is off. As in:

```
GPIO.output(3,GPIO.LOW)
```

Should be:

```
GPIO.output(3,LOW)
```

I think that's why my suggestion of 1,0,True,False wasn't working. These shouldn't have "GPIO." In front of them.

Let me know if that works

-Cheers

Comment: GPIO.output(3,LOW) does not work (error).
GPIO.output(3,0) works.
GPIO.output(3,GPIO.LOW) works.
but the ones that work still print ^[[B.

Comment: I'm realizing that the code looks a little different for the B+ examples I found online. (I do not have the B+).    Sorry, for the bad info :(